# getting error while inserting data to mysql database in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

My database is working fine with my laravel application but while i was trying to insert data to my database i am facing a error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `articles` (`article_head`,
>   `article_body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , 2016-04-27
>   18:40:58, 2016-04-27 18:40:58))

My view file

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('saving_data') }}">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="write_heading">Write Heading:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="10" id="write_heading" name="article_head" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
      <label for="write_post">Write Post:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" cols="10" id="write_post" name="article_body" placeholder="write something awesome!!" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
      <br>
      <div class="model-footer">
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary create_button'>Create</button>
        <button type='reset' class='btn btn-default reset_button'>Reset</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger close_button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

my controller code

```
class ArticleEditor extends Controller
{
    //insert article to database
    public function insert_article(Request $request) {

      $Article = new article;

      $Article->article_head = $request->article_head;
      $Article->article_body = $request->article_body;

      $Article->save();

      return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Migration file

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('article_id');
            $table->string('article_head', 500);
            $table->string('article_body', 10000);
            $table->dateTime('created_on');
        });
    }
```

Comment: As a note: To format code all you need to do is indent with four spaces or use the `{}` button to do it for you.

Comment: ok i will take care of that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query tries to update timestamps.

You need to use `$table->timestamps();` in your migration or add this to your model if you don't want to use them:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

More info about timestamps is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

Comment: but what should i do if i want to update mu current timestamps?

Answer (score -1):

**MySQL:**

```
create table users(id int(10) unsigned auto_increment not null,name varchar(255) not null,email varchar(255) unique,password varchar(255) not null,remember_token varchar(100),created_at timestamp,updated_at  timestamp,  primary key (id))
```